# PHPstorm quick jump to line end with keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, webstorm, usability

How to create shortcuts to line endings with phpstorm.

I have found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCVwdvufTds
In example at 1:27 author is pressing some keyboard shortcut, which creates virtual symbols at the end of lines, and when he press a key, to cursor is moving to that place in file.

Please tell me how to do this, thats awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AceJump plugin** -- http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=phpStorm

Install via `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Plugins | Browse Repositories`

Comment: thanks thats it :)
i found QuickJump too, which i think its better for me